# Project 'app' not found in root project 'MobileBuy'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
>   Project 'app' not found in root project 'MobileBuy'.

getting above error when I build project. but in my android project no app folder then why this Project 'app' not found in root project 'MobileBuy' getting this error.

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':sample', ':buy3', ':buy3-pay-support', ':graphql-java-support'
project(':graphql-java-support').projectDir = new File('./libs/graphql_java_gen/support')
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath dep.androidPlugin
    classpath dep.retrolambda
    classpath dep.butterknifePlugin
    classpath dep.apolloPlugin
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'
android {
compileSdkVersion androidConfig.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion androidConfig.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shopify.sample"
    minSdkVersion androidConfig.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion androidConfig.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    all {
        buildConfigField 'okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level', 'OKHTTP_LOG_LEVEL', 'okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY'

        // We pull the shop settings either from the Environment or a file called shop.properties at the root of the project.
        // Environment variables will take precedence, we will attempt to read those first.
        def shopDomain
        def apiKey
        def androidPayPublicKey
        def androidPayEnvironment

        // get the shop setting from the environment if there any
        shopDomain = System.getenv("SHOP_DOMAIN")
        apiKey = System.getenv("API_KEY")
        androidPayPublicKey = System.getenv("ANDROID_PAY_PUBLIC_KEY")
        androidPayEnvironment = System.getenv("ANDROID_PAY_ENVIRONMENT")

        // pull the store properties from the local file if it exists.  Environment variables take precedence
        def shopProperties = new Properties();
        File shopPropertiesFile = project.file('shop.properties')

        if (shopPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            shopProperties.load(new FileInputStream(shopPropertiesFile))
            shopDomain = shopDomain ?: shopProperties["SHOP_DOMAIN"]
            apiKey = apiKey ?: shopProperties["API_KEY"]
            androidPayPublicKey = androidPayPublicKey ?: shopProperties["ANDROID_PAY_PUBLIC_KEY"]
            androidPayEnvironment = androidPayEnvironment ?: shopProperties["ANDROID_PAY_ENVIRONMENT"]
        }

        if (!shopDomain) {
            shopDomain = ""
        }
        if (!apiKey) {
            apiKey = ""
        }
        if (!androidPayPublicKey) {
            androidPayPublicKey = ""
        }
        if (!androidPayEnvironment) {
            androidPayEnvironment = "com.google.android.gms.wallet.WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX"
        }

        buildConfigField "String", "SHOP_DOMAIN", "\"" + shopDomain.toString() + "\""
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"" + apiKey.toString() + "\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ANDROID_PAY_PUBLIC_KEY", "\"" + androidPayPublicKey.toString() + "\""
        buildConfigField "int", "ANDROID_PAY_ENVIRONMENT", androidPayEnvironment

        debuggable = true
        minifyEnabled = false
    }
}
productFlavors {
    shopify {
    }

    xApollo {
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
 dependencies {
compile dep.androidSupportDesign
compile dep.androidSupportV4
compile dep.androidSupportV7
compile dep.androidSupportAnnotations
compile dep.rxAndroid
compile dep.rxJava
compile dep.timber
compile dep.butterKnife
compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
compile 'com.ss.bottomnavigation:bottomnavigation:1.5.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
annotationProcessor dep.butterKnifeCompiler
compile(dep.fresco) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile dep.constraintLayout
compile dep.rxrelay
compile dep.archRuntime
compile dep.archExt
annotationProcessor dep.arcCompiler
compile project(':buy3-pay-support')
shopifyCompile project(':buy3')
xApolloCompile dep.apolloRuntime
xApolloCompile dep.okhttpLogging
xApolloCompile dep.apolloHttpCache
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
}
 task downloadApolloSchema(type: DefaultTask, group: "GraphQL", description: "Download GraphQL store front API schema") {
doLast {
    println("Downloading GraphQL schema...")
    def schemaFile = new File(project.projectDir.absolutePath + '/src/xApollo/graphql/com/shopify/sample/domain/schema.json')
    if (schemaFile.exists()) {
        schemaFile.delete()
    }
    new URL('https://app.shopify.com/services/ping/storefront_graphql_schema').withInputStream { i ->
        schemaFile.withOutputStream {
            it << i
        }
    }
    println("GraphQL schema has been downloaded!")
}
}

apollo {
customTypeMapping['URL'] = "String"
customTypeMapping['HTML'] = "String"
customTypeMapping['Money'] = "java.math.BigDecimal"
nullableValueType = "apolloOptional"
generateAccessors = false
useSemanticNaming = false
}
```

Comment: Add `build.gradle` code plz

Comment: please reformat your question properly